# "Out of office" Calendar in Office 365/Outlook

Tags: calendar, outlook, office365

All,

I was wondering if there is any way that you know of to automatically populate a Calendar in Office 365/Outlook based on what other users enter to their calendar.

The HR manager wants to have a calendar that shows when employees are out of office all in one place. Having a shared out of office calendar people can "invite" makes sense, however he believes people will forget to do this and it wouldn't be effective!

I've so far found no obvious way of doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The closest built-in feature to a global or master calendar is not a single calendar, but the ability to overlay multiple calendars in Outlook's Calendar module.  External calendars would of course have to be shared/delegated to you first, but you would at least have a central point to view appointments from multiple people using this method.

However, if you prefer a single Calendar but need appointments from other Calendars in it, then you're definitely looking at synchronization - but you can't synchronize multiple calendars in Outlook natively.  For that you'll need to look at a custom solution (such as an add-in) or third-party tools:

http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/sharing/more-tools-and-utilities-for-sharing-data/

Answer (score 0):

You could develop an app or a service that uses [Outlook Calendar REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations).
Your service would poll the employees calendars, compare their status with a local database and create new events on your shared calendar using again the Outlook API.